# Show acronyms in small caps for section headings using the glossaries package

Tags: glossaries, small-caps

The recommended way when using glossaries is to avoid `\gls` for section headings, but to use `\glsentryshort`, `\glsentrylong` or `\glsentryfull`.

In my case I use small-caps for acronyms which work fine in body text.
How can I tell `glossaries` to format the acronym using small-caps in the section headings when using, e.g., `\glsentryshort`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage[xindy,acronym,toc,smallcaps,nomain]{glossaries}
\newacronym{acronym}{acronym}{Small Caps Acronym}

\begin{document}
\section{A section header with an \glsentryshort{acronym}}
\section{But \textsc{small caps} work}
Plain text with \gls{acronym}.
\end{document}
```

shows the problem:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short way is to define a command `\glssc` which wraps around `\textsc{\glsentryshort{#1}}`

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage[xindy,acronym,toc,smallcaps,nomain]{glossaries}
\newacronym{acronym}{acronym}{Small Caps Acronym}

\newcommand{\glssc}[1]{\textsc{\glsentryshort{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\section{A section header with an \glssc{acronym}}
\section{But \textsc{small caps} work}
Plain text with \gls{acronym}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hm, that's also a good pragmatic solution. Currently, I put the \textsc directly in the acronym definition to make sure it works in headings. I was just hoping that maybe there exists a setting etc. to make glossaries actually deal with such a scenario. Because I find the current behavior of glossaries not really consistent.

Comment: @Benjamin: Hm, depends on the request. You could define an `acronymstyle` of your own of course